# Why is using try / catch a bad idea in this scenario?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, try-catch

I've been working on hooking up mongoDB to a node.js server. I've got the code all neatly put away, however it takes about 5~ seconds to connect, and if a request for an insert or a query comes before that, the server will crash.

My first instinct was to use try/catch to filter off any requests which error out. I will want the server to go on regardless of what errors an individual request breaks, so why not use it?

Everywhere I look it's touted as a bad idea, I'm not sure I understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A try/catch block around something that simply ignores the error is generally considered bad practice.  However, if that is the behavior you want, then there is nothing wrong with it.  Just consider that it may not actually be the best behavior.  You may, at a minimum, want to log the fact that an exception occurred.

Now, due to the asynchronous nature of Node.js, try/catch blocks are sometimes not useful.  I don't know what part of the MongoDB API you are using, but if there is a callback, you will want to instead check the `err` parameter, which should be the first parameter of your callback function in most cases.

Finally, for all of my applications, I connect to any necessary DBs synchronously, and start listening on ports afterwards.  But, this is only relevant if a persistent connection makes sense for your project.  Plus, you still have to watch for errors, which can occur as connection failures do happen.

Comment: How do you force a connection to, say, mongoDB to be synchronous? That'd eliminate my problem, I think

Comment: @dsp_099, What client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using mongodb 1.3.6 and redis 0.8.3

Comment: @dsp_099, What client library are you using?  That has nothing to do with the server.  There are lots of ways to connect to Mongo.

Comment: I pulled those out of the package.json. The actual libraries are node-mongodb-native and node_redis, I think?

Comment: @dsp_099, Then, just call your other code from the callback in `.connect()`.

Comment: I see. I suppose maybe my question from the start really was - is there a way to avoid that? Last time I touched node.js, it was a couple of calls and I was knee-deep in some pretty epic spaghetti code that went levels and levels down...

Comment: @dsp_099, Yeah, it all depends on how your application is structured.  Unfortunately, there is no straight answer, and there are a million opinions.  The bulk of my Node.js applications have been <100 lines, so it hasn't been a real problem.  The 2 larger applications I have built were structured in such a way where the parts serving the data were in separate classes, so the base bootstrapping application was clean.